# weak property (delegate) still causing retain cycle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

This is bizarre.  I have what I think is a typical delegate property declaration:

```
@property (weak) id<BTSAudioStreamerDelegate> delegate;
```

If I assign to it from another object:

```
btsAudioStreamer.delegate = self;
```

It is retaining the delegate!  I have an NSLog in dealloc and it doesn't get called.  If I comment out the delegate assignment line, it does.  Also the first object plays audio, and if it doesn't dealloc, I end up with two audio streams playing at the same time.  Not good!  How can I debug this?

EDIT: I should mention that I am setting btsAudioStreamer.delegate = nil before allocing any new objects.

Comment: Is the assignment happening inside a block? If it's the only time 'self' is referenced, then it would cause self to be captured and retained.

Comment: Confirm your theory by using Instruments to find exactly where the object is being retained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124425/mkmapview-autorelease-not-calling-dealloc-after-uiviewcontroller-is-popped/21541599#21541599

Comment: @Catfish_Man no blocks.

Comment: @Darren thanks - that link with the detailed instructions for Instruments was exactly what I needed.  It was an NSTimer.  I forgot that they retain the objects that launch them!  The delegate thing was a total red herring.  If the delegate exists, I set up a timer to send messages back to the delegate. Probably should have used KVO on a property instead. Anyway, if you make your response an answer I will accept it.