# Unloading MKMapView after pop from Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have 2 view controllers, first one, named `InitialVC`, containing a `UIButton` which pushes the 2nd view controller when clicked. `InitialVC` is embedded in `UINavigationController`.

The second view controller is `MapVC`, which contains a `MKMapView` and a back button.

When `InitialVC` is loaded, memory usage is **30MB**. Then when it is pushed into `MapVC`, memory usage jumps to **100MB**. When I press the back button to navigate back to `InitialVC`, the memory usage is still **100MB**.

*That means, `MKMapView` is still running in the background.*

I don't want this, which will definitely cause performance issues. I understand that by default, the `MKMapView` will unload once memory warning is issued ( in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` ), but **my question is**, is it a good practice to dealloc the `MKMapView` in `viewWillDisappear` / `viewDidUnload` / `viewDidDisappear` / `viewWillUnload` etc ? or is there any better to control the memory usage ?

If you need codes, here it is (nothing special):

**InitialVC.m**

```
- (IBAction)clickMap:(id)sender {
  MapVC *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapVC"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

**MapVC.m**

```
@interface MapVC {
  IBOutlet MKMapView *map_view;
}
@end

- (IBAction)clickBack:(id)sender {
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I didn't setup a `@property` for `MKMapView`, as it is not used in other classes.

Additional information:

- Using ARC
- Using Storyboard
- Using iOS 7 SDK
- Using Xcode 5.x

*Note: this question may apply to cases other than `MKMapView` too.*

---

*Update:*

After changing the strong reference in `@interface` to:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *map_view;
```

The memory pattern is now:

- Loaded `InitialVC`: **30MB**
- Push into `MapVC`: **100MB**
- Pop back to `InitialVC`: **90MB**
- Push into `MapVC`: **100MB**
- Pop back to `InitialVC`: **90MB**

The memory issue is slightly relieved.

---

*Update 2:*

dealloc test is performed; `- (void)dealloc` didn't get called

---

*Update 3:*

There is a `MKMapViewDelegate` connected, and a non-repeating `NSTimer` event which triggers when user drags the map. There is also a `AFNetworking` 2 block-based notification in the `NSTimer` event, which fetches data from server and update the annotations on the map. Note: The server response completed successfully.

Comment: "That means, MKMapView is still running in the background." No it doesn't. It just means a lot of memory is still being used. Don't guess! Implement `dealloc` and log; if your log is never called, _then_ you know the MapVC has not ceased to exist.

Comment: But should I call `dealloc` manually? Some suggested `dealloc` should not be called manually after using ARC.

Comment: `@interface MapVC {IBOutlet MKMapView *map_view;}` That could certainly be a problem, because this is a strong reference under ARC. Use a weak ref thru a property. You can make a private property using a class-extension, so other classes won't see it.

Comment: No, never call it. You just want to know if it is being called.

Comment: @matt maybe you can put this as an answer, with a little bit more sample codes about *weak ref thru property* or *using class extension* ?

Comment: It isn't an answer. We are still trying to focus in on whether there is a problem and, if so, what it is.

Comment: @matt please see my update in question, thanks.

Comment: You still didn't even do the dealloc test. We're getting nowhere.

Comment: performed the `dealloc` test. Didn't get called.

Comment: So now we know you have a retain cycle. Now you have to find it. MapVC is retaining something that is retaining MapVC. Do you use any timers? Any blocks (esp. block-based notifications)? Does anything inside MapVC have an explicit reference to MapVC?

Comment: Oh, sorry, one more thing: did you try the Leaks tool in Instruments? It can sometimes track down a retain cycle for you.

Comment: see my update, thank you. Didn't try Leaks yet. I just use Xcode 5's memory Debug Session.

Comment: See this answer for more help with tracing retain/release in Instruments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21541599/341994

Comment: As @matt said, you should use `__weak` on your `ivar`. Furthermore, it's recommended to use Instruments to debug memory issues, and do it on a device too.

Comment: Also you might try running the static analyzer: it _sometimes_ spots potential memory issues.

Comment: If you get desperate (ha), just start commenting out entire bits of functionality. For example, comment out the timer/networking thing completely so that no timer ever fires and no networking happens. Now push/pop and see if dealloc is called; either way you'll have learned something important!

Comment: Another thing to try is to start nilifying things in `viewWillDisappear:`. Nilify every reference to `self` that you can find. For example, you are the map view's delegate so set `mapview.delegate = nil`. And so forth.

Comment: Also do you use any core animation delegates? A CAAnimation retains its delegate, which is very weird (though understandable) and has caught me with my pants down several times.

Comment: Will try these tools & tests one-by-one; didn't use Core Animations. The only animation I used is the Navigation Controller's push & pop `animated:YES`