# How can I see what pointers are keeping my objects alive in ARC (iOS SDK)?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I have view controllers that aren't be released from memory after a pop and I can't seem to zero-in on the pointers that are keeping them alive. How can I see what pointer variables are pointing to my view controller(s)?

Comment: That's what instruments are for.

Comment: How exactly? I can't figure out how to find this information in instruments.

Comment: It's not super easy. Here's a beginner's tutorial. http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Comment: @TonyFriz Step-by-step instructions for tracking the retain/release history of an object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124425/mkmapview-autorelease-not-calling-dealloc-after-uiviewcontroller-is-popped/21541599#21541599

Comment: Thanks @Darren, I was able to figure it out with your post.